# VB equivalent of C# ?? operator

Tags: c#, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a VB.NET equivalent for C#'s ?? operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403445/is-there-a-vb-net-equivalent-for-cs-operator)

Is there an equivalent in VB.NET to C#'s ?? operator?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403445/is-there-a-vb-net-equivalent-for-cs-operator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629036/coalesce-operator-and-conditional-operator-in-vb-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2hxce09y.aspx) (Null coalescing).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403445/is-there-a-vb-net-equivalent-for-cs-operator

Comment: The table you linked to correctly shows that there is an equivalent.