# Exclude null values while summation by specific column in a left joined table using LINQ

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, linq

I have read a few answers on SO regarding but I think they don't address my problem. I would be happy if someone can point me to one that is relevant. Consider the following tables:

[image]

There can be various rates at which a booking may be charged and there can be *multiple or no charges per booking*. Each charge has its own rate (in $). So e.g. a vehicle booked can be charged for *Late Arrival* at $200 and for another charge *No Show* at $450. These rates can vary for every booking and not all bookings have charges.

Now I want to show the total amount charged on bookings if there is any. For that, I have the following LINQ query:

```
Dim q = (From b In _db.Bookings
           Select New With {
                .Bid = b.ID,
                <some other columns from booking table>
                .TotalCharges = b.BookingCharges.Sum(Function(o) o.Rate)
           }).ToList()
```

The query returns error:

*"The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."*

Since there are bookings that do not have any charges (NULL) and hence cannot be summed. I have tried to use `.TotalCharges = b.BookingCharges.DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(Function(o) o.Rate)` and `.TotalCharges = b.BookingCharges.Sum(Function(o) o.Rate or 0)` but same error. I have read answers on SO related to this error but I feel the OP has a different problem or query than mine, and also the answers are all C#.

Comment: May be I need something equivalent of SQL's COALESCE(SUM(Rate), 0) in LINQ. I used a utility that converts SQL to LINQ but it just did IF Statement, even that is not yielding the result, giving the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Try using The [If() operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator#if-operator-called-with-two-arguments):

```
Dim q = (From b In _db.Bookings
    Select New With {
        .Bid = b.ID
        .TotalCharges = b.BookingCharges.Sum(Function(o) If(o.Rate,0))
}).ToList()
```

If that doesn't work, maybe try something like this:

```
Dim q = (From b In _db.Bookings
    Select New With {
        .Bid = b.ID
        .TotalCharges = b.BookingCharges.Where(Function(r) r.Rate IsNot Nothing).Sum(Function(o) o.Rate)
}).ToList()
```

Comment: Compile Time Error: BC33107 First operand in a binary 'If' expression must be nullable or a reference type. Should I have to make Rate property nullable? How?

Comment: On your edit, I got this: Error BC31419 'IsNot' requires operands that have reference types, but this operand has the value type 'Integer'. I tried `Function(r) Not IsNothing(r.Rate)` then this error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsNothing(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: What data type is `Rate` in your model?

Comment: Can there be a row in the `BookingCharge` table with a null `Rate`? How is that column defined in the database table? Also, do you actually have records in the `BookingCharge` table?

Comment: It does not allow null in database definition. I changed it to allow null values and at database level, it is accepting null values. I updated the model where under properties of Rate, I can see that `Nullable` property has changed to `None` but the error remains the same. In Model, I changed `Nullable` to `True`, even then the error is same. So I guess it is not due to column Rate accepting null values but because there is **no record** for some bookings since it's left join not an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Applied IF on whole new column not just on the specific column in the joining table (`Rate` Column) because the NULL is not originated from the `Rate` column, it is originating from an empty `BookingCharge` record against a `Booking` (attached to the query as a column `.TotalCharges`) therefore whole column should undergo the IF statement (COALESCENCE).

`.TotalCharges = If(b.BookingCharges.Sum(Function(o) o.Rate) <> Nothing, b.BookingCharges.Sum(Function(o) o.Rate), 0)`

Thanks to Namrehs and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629036/coalesce-operator-and-conditional-operator-in-vb-net) SO answer.