# VB equivalent of C# null coalescing operator - specific case

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am aware that similar questions have been asked before:

- [VB.NET null coalescing operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792729/vb-net-null-coalescing-operator)
- [Coalesce operator and Conditional operator in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629036/coalesce-operator-and-conditional-operator-in-vb-net)

But my issue is not addressed there.  In C# I can write this:

```
return myFoo ??= new Foo()
```

If `myFoo` is null, this line will create  a new `Foo`, assign it to `myFoo`, *and* return the value of `myFoo`.

I want to translate this to VB. I can do it in two statements e.g.:

```
If myFoo Is Nothing Then myFoo = New Foo()
Return myFoo
```

or even using the two-argument `If` function:

```
myFoo = If(myFoo, New Foo())
Return myFoo
```

I would prefer to do it in one statement. This *looks* like it ought to be equivalent to the C# version:

```
Return myFoo = If(myFoo, New Foo())
```

But it doesn't work because it interprets the `=` as a comparator, not an assignment.

Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: I'm no VB expert, but I don't think it has a null-coalescing assignment operator like C# does.

Comment: It's simply not possible to do it in a single line in VB. In C#, assignments effectively return the value that was assigned but that's not the case in VB. This is basically the same situation as trying to translate something like `if (boolVar = boolValue)`. That can't be done in VB and neither can what you want. You have to use two separate lines.

Comment: I'm also wondering what's the use case where you need this. You're returning that object out of this function anyway. `Return If(myFoo, New Foo())` should be sufficient, no?

Comment: @msmolcic It's often used with caching. The method gets a (cached) `Foo`, creating it first and storing it in the cache if appropriate

Comment: Is `myFoo` a local or a global variable?

Comment: @canton7 I see what you're saying, right. I'm usually prefixing my class fields with an underscore so I thought `myFoo` is either a function parameter or variable created within a function itself.

Comment: The major difference here is that VB has an [Assignment Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/statements#assignment-statements) whereas C# has an assignment *expression*. The difference between the two is that expressions produce values, statements do not.

Comment: `I would prefer to do it in one line` - well, `myFoo = If(myFoo, New Foo()) : Return myFoo` is one line...

Comment: You could get close if you wrote your own version of `If` that returned the value and assigned it using `ByRef`, but that's a horrible hack and probably has other issues.

Comment: @GSerg.  My sloppiness, I meant 'one statement', not 'one line'.

Comment: @canton7 if you want to cache, `Lazy(Of T)` provides that functionality.  Then just return the `Value` member and it will run the factory function if needed.

Comment: @Craig It requires an extra few object allocations, and a bunch of additional cost (in order to be properly thread-safe) which isn't necessary if you're just doing something lightweight and single-threaded. I mean if `Foo` is reasonably cheap, you gain nothing by substituting the creation of the `Foo` with the creation of a `Lazy<Foo>` instead

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: This is the crux of the issue - you should write it up as the answer.

Comment: @RichardPawson - "I would prefer to do it in one statement. "  Why?

Comment: @dbasnett.  It's vaguely annoying that one statement in C# has to be two in VB, but it's no great problem to have to use two statements, I just wondered if there was a more elegant way to code it. The habit of defining all functions as a single expression comes from functional programming, but - before  anyone else points it out - caching myFoo is not permissible in functional programming anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C-heritage languages (which includes C#) have historically treated assignment as an **expression** which means that it has a result.  Historically, that result is the value that was assigned.  This has advantages, which includes allowing more concise multiple assignments and testing results of assignment in conditionals.  It also has disadvantages, which include potential confusion of assignment and equality operators in conditionals.

Other languages treat assignment as a **statement** which means that it does not have a result and cannot be composed into another operation.  VB is one of these languages (others include Fortran and Pascal).

Because assignment is a statement in VB, you cannot assign and test in the same operation unless you write your own function to do so.  You will have to do your two-line operation, or use the `:` statement separator to put both statements on one line.

Idle curiosity on VB that relates to language families: pre-.NET, VB had much more in common with Fortran than C.  The end block statements follow the same conventions as Fortran, the code editor will recognize `EndIf` and convert it to `End If`, the array layout was the same (column-major instead of row-major), and the code editor would recognize the Fortran convention for a double-precision constant e.g. `1.0d0` would be treated as a double `1.0`.  The last two have been lost with the move to .NET.