# One line if in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, conditional-operator

Is it possible to do one line if statement in VB .NET? If so, how?

Comment: Be careful with the IIf opertor though - it is not always [short-circuited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and both the true and false expressions are evaluated.

Comment: I actually think IIF is *never* short-circuited

Comment: What's the advantage - or even the purpose - of IFF over If?

Comment: @LeoKing Backwards compatibility with VB6. Single "I" IF was introduced in VB.NET, whereas Double "I" IIF existed before. And I don't believe any part of VB6 supported short circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Use IF().

It is a short-circuiting ternary operator.

```
Dim Result = IF(expression,<true return>,<false return>)
```

SEE ALSO:

- [IIF becomes If, and a true ternary operator](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/2007/05/08/iif-becomes-if-and-a-true-ternary-operator/)
- [Is there a conditional ternary
  operator in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net)
- [Orcas introduces the IF operator - a
  new and improved IIF](http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2008/03/11/if-operator-a-new-and-improved-iif-sophia-salim.aspx)
- [The Ternary Operator in VB.NET](http://blog.dmbcllc.com/2007/11/29/the-ternary-operator-in-vbnet/)

Comment: Note that there can be implicit type casting.  For instance:   `If(x.HasValue, x.Value, Nothing)`  will return 0 if x doesn't contain a value.  One way to remedy can be to force value to Nullable like so: `If(x.HasValue, CType( x.Value, Nullable( of Integer) ), Nothing)`

Comment: @LosManos FYI, The reason for the result you got is as follows:  If `x` has type `Integer?`, then `x.Value` has type `Integer`, NOT `Integer?`. So the compiler is correct to convert Nothing to `Integer` (to match the other result), resulting in `0`. Just explaining the compiler's behaviour; what you did is a fine solution for what you wanted. An alternative solution, would be to cast the Nothing to the desired type, e.g. `DirectCast(Nothing, Integer?)`.

Comment: Are you saying that If is checking the type returned by ExpressionIfTrue when it returns ExpressionIfFalse?

Answer (score 25):

It's actually pretty simple..

```
If CONDITION Then ..INSERT CODE HERE..
```

Comment: Yes. Despite I hate this, putting `If...Then...Else...` statements on one line is possible. However, be aware when you combine it with putting multiple statements on one line using colons. The statement `If <condition> Then <action1> : <action2>` will only execute action2 in combination with action 1! Action2 is not a separate statement by itself! So for clarity, I would advise to _always_ use block statements and avoid colons altogether.

Answer (score 20):

**Single line**

Syntax:

```
If (condition) Then (do this)
```

Example:

```
If flag = true Then i = 1
```

**Multiple ElseIf's**

Syntax:

```
If (condition) Then : (do this)
ElseIf (condition2) Then : (do this)
Else : (do this)
End If
```

OR

```
If (condition) Then : (do this) : ElseIf (condition2) Then : (do this) : Else : (do this) : End If
```

**Multiple operations**

Syntax:

```
If (condition) Then : (do this) : (and this) : End If
```

Answer (score 17):

At the risk of causing some cringing by purests and c# programmers, you can use multiple statements and else in a one-line if statement in VB. In this example, y ends up 3 and not 7.

```
i = 1
If i = 1 Then x = 3 : y = 3 Else x = 7 : y = 7
```

Comment: @BrianWebster Nice. I hate it. :)

Answer (score 7):

Or

```
IIf(CONDITION, TRUE_ACTION, FALSE_ACTION)
```

Comment: And this is an expression, while the question asked for a statement. ;-)

Comment: The downside to `IIf` vs the identical syntax with `If` is that `IIf` is more prone to [run-time errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Just add `Then`:

```
If A = 1 Then A = 2
```

or:

```
If A = 1 Then _
    A = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

### **One Line 'If Statement'**

Easier than you think, noticed no-one has put what I've got yet, so I'll throw in my 2-cents.

In my testing you don't need the `continuation? semi-colon`, you can do without, also you can do it without the `End If`.

`<C#> = Condition.`

`<R#> = True Return.`

`<E> = Else Return.`

**Single Condition**

```
If <C1> Then <R1> Else <E>
```

**Multiple Conditions**

```
If <C1> Then <R1> Else If <C2> Then <R2> Else <E>
```

**Infinite? Conditions**

```
If <C1> Then <R1> Else If <C2> Then <R2> If <C3> Then <R3> If <C4> Then <R4> Else...
' Just keep adding "If <C> Then <R> Else" to get more
```

*-Not really sure how to format this to make it more readable, so if someone could offer a edit, please do-*

Answer (score 3):

```
If (X1= 1) Then : Val1= "Yes" : Else : Val1= "Not" : End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IIf function too:

```
CheckIt = IIf(TestMe > 1000, "Large", "Small")
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple to use in VB.NET code

**Basic Syntax 
IIF(Expression as Boolean,True Part as Object,False Part as Object)As Object**

1. Using IIF same as Ternary
2. Dim myVariable as string= " "
3. myVariable = IIf(Condition, True,False)

Answer (score 0):

```
If (condition, condition_is_true, condition_is_false)
```

It will look like this in longer version:

```
If (condition_is_true) Then 

Else (condition_is_false)

End If
```