# If textbox.text = more then 1 option

Tags: vb.net

This should be the easiest question all day!

All I want to see is how to condense some code.

Example:

```
If textbox.text = "0000" then
'do something
End If

If textbox.text = "0001" then
    'do something
    End If
```

What I want to do, is have that in 1 statement.

Comment: One statement or one block?

Comment: This may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771273/one-line-if-in-vb-net

Comment: do you mean `If textbox.text = "0000" OR textbox.text = "0001" then`?

Comment: @TonyHinkle Like,

'If textbox.text = "0000" "0001" "0002" then

Comment: also take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eefw3xsy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @Lashane Yes, exactly

Comment: To be pedantic, if your goal is to write cleaner code then I would advise against writing any app logic in the UI layer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `.Contains` from an array of data. Here is a simple example.

```
Dim choices = {"0000","0001","0002"}  
If choices.Contains(textbox.text) Then
  'do something
End If
```

Comment: If `do something` is the same thing, then that is one thing, but if `do something` is different based on the value of textbox.txt that is another thing...

Comment: It was my fault with my wording. This is what I wanted tho. Thanks abunch!

Answer (score 2):

If you want each condition to do something different:

`If testbox.text = "0000" Then Do.Something Else If testbox.text = "0001" Then Do.SomethingDifferent`

If you have multiple conditions to test to do the same thing:

`If testbox.text = "0000" OR testbox.text = "0001" OR testbox.text = "0002" Then Do.Something`

Comment: Tony, always a big help