# How would I shorten this If... Else... statement to check the state of a Date?

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-conversion

I am a C# programmer but dabbling in VB.Net because everybody else in my team uses it. In the interests of professional development I would like to shrink the following If... Else... statement.

```
If cmd.Parameters("@whenUpdated").Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
    item.WhenUpdated = Nothing
Else
    item.WhenUpdated = cmd.Parameters("@whenUpdated").Value
End If
```

I appreciate examples are already available however I can not get it working for this specific case.

Cheers, Ian.

Comment: While not very obvious, this is almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net

Comment: Isn't that the wrong way around?

Comment: Thank you I saw that question but didn't understand how to apply it in this situation. I see you have voted to close. That's fine I have the answer I need.

Comment: @Mark it is I am working very late I apologise I will turn it round.

Comment: @Ian: I am sorry about that. The "I am a C# programmer" preface of your question made me conclude that you probably knew about the `?:` syntax and wanted something similar.

Comment: Thanks @Cresults I am finding it very interesting and not dissimilar to VBA! :-D

Comment: @Jørn, sure I know how to do it in C# but for some reason it wasn't directly copying over to VB.Net. As I have said I am working very late I need to sleep... or get coffee! 8-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use If as a function rather than a statement:

```
item.WhenUpdated = If(cmd.Parameters("@whenUpdated").Equals(DBNull.Value), cmd.Parameters("@whenUpdated").Value, Nothing)
```

Comment: You still have to put this twice `cmd.Parameters("@whenUpdated").Value`. Why not write a DBNull2Nothing function? Make it much shorter & self documenting?

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the ternary operator in C#, VB has the [**IIF function**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28VS.80%29.aspx).

```
item.WhenUpdated = IIF(cmd.Parameters("@whenUpdated").Equals(DBNull.Value),
                            cmd.Parameters("@whenUpdated").Value, 
                            Nothing)
```

If the first argument (the boolean expression) evaluates to true, then the second argument is returned from the function.  If the first argument is false, then the third argument is returned.

Comment: The IIf function doesn't short-circuit and returns type Object, which must be cast. As long as you're using VB2008, it's better to use the new If ternary operator instead.

Comment: Good to know.  I dropped VB a few years back and haven't done much with it since.

Comment: Some people have all the luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
item.WhenUpdated = Nothing
If cmd.Parameters("@whenUpdated").Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
    item.WhenUpdated = cmd.Parameters("@whenUpdated").Value
End If
```

Only 1 line, but still shorter.

The `IF` function is definitely the shortest, but not the most readable.

Comment: You could also put the =Nothing at the declaration, so Dim WhenUpdated as Date = Nothing. That'd save another line :-)

Comment: I can't do that @CResults as it is a data object. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One less line

```
item.WhenUpdated = Nothing
If cmd.Parameters("@whenUpdated").Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
    item.WhenUpdated = cmd.Parameters("@whenUpdated").Value
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the operator If(...) if you want short-circuiting behavior.

Use the function IIf(...) if you don't want short-circuiting behavior.