# Make An Integer Null

Tags: vb.net, nullable

I have an update function that updates an sql server db table through a dataset. One of the fields in the table is an integer and accepts null values. So when I am populating the update function I need a way to enter a null in when the function wants an integer.

I tried to do it this way but  `_intDLocation = ""` throws an exception

```
Dim _dLocation As String = udDefaultLocationTextEdit.Text
    Dim _intDLocation As Integer
    If _dLocation <> "" Then
        _intDLocation = Integer.Parse(udDefaultLocationTextEdit.Text)
    Else
        'NEED HELP HERE
        _intDLocation = ""
    End If
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Integers cannot be set to Null.  You have to make the integer "nullable" by adding a question mark after the word Integer.  Now _intDLocation is no longer a normal integer.  It is an instance of `Nullable(Of Integer)`.

```
Dim _dLocation As String = udDefaultLocationTextEdit.Text
Dim _intDLocation As Integer?
If _dLocation <> "" Then
    _intDLocation = Integer.Parse(udDefaultLocationTextEdit.Text)
Else
    _intDLocation = Nothing
End If
```

Later on, if you want to check for null you can use this handy, readable syntax:

```
If _intDLocation.HasValue Then
   DoSomething()
End If
```

In some cases you will need to access the value as an actual integer, not a nullable integer.  For those cases, you simply access

```
_intDLocation.Value
```

Read all about Nullable [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Dim _dLocation As String = udDefaultLocationTextEdit.Text

Dim _intDLocation As Nullable(Of  Integer)

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_dLocation) Then
     _intDLocation = Integer.Parse(_dLocation)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

My application uses a lot of labels that start out blank (Text property), but need to be incremented as integers, so I made this handy function:

```
    Public Shared Function Nullinator(ByVal CheckVal As String) As Integer
    ' Receives a string and returns an integer (zero if Null or Empty or original value)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(CheckVal) Then
        Return 0
    Else
        Return CheckVal
    End If
End Function
```

This is typical example of how it would be used:

```
Dim Match_Innings As Integer = Nullinator(Me.TotalInnings.Text)
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score -3):

```
_intDLocation = Nothing
```

Comment: This is the same as _intDLocation = 0