# What is the VB .Net equivalent of the C# shortcut test for something to be true or false?

Tags: c#, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a conditional ternary operator in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net)

C# has a shortcut like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p2", ((supplierID > 0) ? (object)supplierID : DBNull.Value)));
```

Just curious if VB .Net has something like that too?

Answer (score 1):

```
If((supplierID > 0, (object)supplierID, DBNull.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@p2", (If((supplierID > 0), DirectCast(supplierID, Object), DBNull.Value))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a "ternary operator"

http://blog.dmbcllc.com/2007/11/29/the-ternary-operator-in-vbnet/

Comment: Yes, it's a ternary operator, but it's actually called the **IF** operator. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2008/03/11/if-operator-a-new-and-improved-iif-sophia-salim.aspx