# Is there a version of the shorthand If-Then-Else in C# (cond ? a : b), in VB.Net?

Tags: c#, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a conditional ternary operator in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net)

Is there a version of the shorthand If-Then-Else in C#:

```
c = (a > b) ? a : b;
```

meaning...

```
if (a > b) {
  c = a; }
else {
  c = b; }
```

.. in VB.Net?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net and YES

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to use the [If operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx):

```
Dim maximum = If(a > b, a, b)
```

There's also the older [Iif function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d.aspx), which still works, but `If` is superior, since it:

- performs type inference (if `a` and `b` are both integers, the return value will be an integer instead of an object) and
- short-cuts the operation (if `a > b`, only `a` is evaluated, and vice-versa) -- this is relevant if `a` or `b` is a function call.

Answer (score 6):

Yes the `IF` is what you want

Here is some reference

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985

Here is its use

```
c = IF(a > b, a , b)
```

Obviously there was a operator called [IIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d) but it has been deprecated.

Comment: this is super deprecated, it's now just If.

Comment: Strictly I believe `IIf` is a *function* and `If` is an *operator*

Comment: @MarkJ exactly, IIf hsa more overhead

Comment: Public Function IIf(ByVal Expression As Boolean, ByVal TruePart As Object, ByVal FalsePart As Object) As Object

<- is definitely a function.