# VB.NET Nullables

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, nullable

I'm experiencing unpredicted effects with nullables in VB.net. The object in question has a property defined:

```
Public Property Value As Int32?
```

When I try to coalesce the value using `IIf`, I get a null exception

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HOValue", IIf(headOffice.Value.HasValue, headOffice.Value .Value, DBNull.Value))
```

In C#, I know there's no implicit conversion for nullables, hence you can't use `??`, but why is the first part of the IIf being evaluated in VB.NET?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/576431

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Iff` is a function, i.e. its arguments are evaluated before it is executed. When `headOffice.Value` is null, then `headOffice.Value.Value` cannot be evaluated here.

Comment: That makes sense and intensifies my VB hatred even more. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: @Echilon there is also a 3-part `If` that does what you want without this pain.

Comment: The if statement in vb 2008 and higher can act like the ternary operator you seek.  If(headOffice.Value.HasValue, headOffice.Value.Value, DBNull.Value)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2008/03/11/if-operator-a-new-and-improved-iif-sophia-salim.aspx

Answer (score 9):

The reson for this is that `Iif` is a function, so both the `true` value and `false` value are evaluated before the condition.

Instead, use `If` i.e.:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HOValue", If(headOffice.Value.HasValue, headOffice.Value.Value, DBNull.Value)) ' Assuming you've already checked that headOffice.Value IsNot Nothing
```