# how to convert the sign "?" in c# to vb.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, operators

I am trying to convert c# code to vb.net but I have difficulties in converting the sign "?" in c# to vb.net. here my code to convert

```
 public audit_trail Mapper(IDataReader rdr)
 {
      audit_trail audit_trail = new audit_trail();
      audit_trail.Log_id = rdr["Log_id"] is DBNull ? 0 : (int)rdr["Log_id"];            
      audit_trail.Host = rdr["Host"] is DBNull ? string.Empty : (string)rdr["Host"];
      return audit_trail;
 }
```

how to convert the sign "?" to vb.net??

I would like to convert

```
  audit_trail.Host = rdr["Host"] is DBNull ? string.Empty : (string)rdr["Host"];
```

to something like

```
if rdr["Host"] is DBNull.Value then
  audit_trail.Host =  string.Empty 
else 
  audit_trail.Host = rdr["Host"]
end if
```

but the code is too long, too many line of code.. do you guys have an idea to convert to the short one?

Comment: See [Is there a conditional ternary operator in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 6):

The visual basic syntax for the ternary operator is `If([condition,] op1, op2)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
audit_trail.Host = If(IsDBNull(rdr("Host")), String.Empty, CType(rdr("Host"), String))
```