# Convert C# line code to VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
literal.Text = (gridView.Controls[i] as CheckBox).Checked ? "True" : "False";
```

How to convert this line to VB.Net syntax, could someone please help me?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net

Comment: You'd best learn to program. In this case the following happens: An element from an array is casted to a checkbox, then the Checked property is converted to a String in a rather cumbersome way.

Comment: *Too localized*? This is an exact duplicate, not too localized. He's asking how to convert that in general, which would help other people in the future if it weren't a duplicate.

Comment: How can this be duplicate? Read the question and then comment

Comment: I know how to program in VB.Net no in C# so please don't mess with people knowledge. u r no god TJHeuvel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 literal.Text = If(TryCast(gridView.Controls(i), CheckBox).Checked, "True", "False")
```

You can always use [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) nice online converter

Comment: +1 because it’s the direct translation but using `TryCast` here (and `as` in C#) is a bit weird since this could result in a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

Cheat.  Use a code converter.  There are free ones online.  Learn from what you get for results.

http://converter.telerik.com/

produces

```
literal.Text = If(TryCast(gridView.Controls(i), CheckBox).Checked, "True", "False")
```

Answer (score 0):

there are online converters you can use to get pretty close for this stuff

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/[1](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

```
literal.Text = If(TryCast(gridView.Controls(i), CheckBox).Checked, "True", "False")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
literal.Text = If(TryCast(gridView.Controls(i), CheckBox).Checked, "True", "False")
```