# using c# condtional operator in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a conditional ternary operator in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net)

I have the folowing code in asp.net for c# website but i have to use this code in vb.net site but i m unable to convert the code even code translator please help me to do this.here is my code

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkStatus" runat="server" 
                            AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkStatus_OnCheckedChanged"
                            Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Approved")) %>'
                            Text='<%# Eval("Approved").ToString().Equals("True") ? " Approved " : " Not Approved " %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>                    
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

here i want to change this line `Text='<%# Eval("Approved").ToString().Equals("True") ? " Approved " : " Not Approved " %>'`

for vb.net site please help me to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`If` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) with at least Framework 3.5 (VS 2008):

```
Text='<%# If(Eval("Approved").ToString().Equals("True"), " Approved ", " Not Approved ") %>'
```