# VB linq to sql isnull

Tags: vb.net, linq, isnull

I want make this in linq to sql

```
select isnull(x.COD, '1') as 'NCOD'
from table x
```

I have tried this.

```
From x In table
select NCOD = x.COD ?? '1';
```

I'm using LINQPad 4 and VB Expression. but LINQPAd says that I can't use ? expression (No se puede usar aquí el carácter '?' in Spanish)

Any idea?

PD: sorry for my English.

Comment: Yes, At the end I used: If(X.COD.toString Is Nothing, "1", x.COD)

Answer (score 1):

If your value type is string, you can use following expression:

```
result = from x in values select IF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(x),"No value",x);
```

If it is a nullable type (like int?, Double?, SomeClass?):

```
result = from x in values select IF(x.HasValue,x,1);
```

Ref:

- Nullable types in VB.NET - http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/nullabletypes.htm
- Warning about VB IF operator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11990998/1732138

Comment: It works, but with String I've used "If(X.COD Is Nothing, "", ccv.COD)" because I had an error with "IF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(x),"No value",x)"

Comment: Yeah, sorry... Got it mixed up with c#. You've got the idea, though.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following query, this will be helpful to you.

```
var InvoiceNo = dbContext.table.where(x => (int?)x.ICOD) ?? "NCOD";
```

Here, **??** works only on nullable int **int?**

And you are a vb.net user than you should use following code, this will be help ful to you...

```
Dim InvoiceNo = If(dbContext.table.where(Function(x) DirectCast(x.ICOD, System.Nullable(Of Integer))), "NCOD")
```

Comment: I'm not sure but It's possible that this is only for C#? It doesn`t work to me because says " can't use ? expression (No se puede usar aquí el carácter '?' in Spanish) "