# Npgsql parameters with NULL value, vb.net

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, parameters, npgsql

I'm running through a loop adding parameters, when I get to a NULL, the program punts.  My statement looks like this:

```
mysql = "Insert into TABLE (field1) VALUES (:Col1)"

mycomm = New NpgsqlCommand (mySQL, conn)

myComm.Parameters.Add("Col" & cCnt, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Double).Value = Obj.value

myComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This works fine if Obj.value is not empty, but if Obj.value is nothing, my Execute statement fails.  I'd like to just insert a NULL value into the DB.  Any ideas?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To insert a NULL value in the database field, you need to pass the [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) to your parameter

You could use the [VB.NET ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net) to check if Obj itself is Nothing or if Obj.Value is nothing and in that case (true) pass the `DBNull.Value` instead of the Obj.Value

```
myComm.Parameters.Add("Col" & cCnt, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Double).Value = 
                      If(Obj Is Nothing OrElse Obj.Value Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Obj.value))
```