# What is the VB.NET equivalent of the C# ? operator?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, iif

What is the `VB.NET` equivalent of the `C#` `?` operator?

For example, how would the following code be written in `VB.NET`?

```
hp.pt = iniFile.GetValue("System", "PT").ToUpper().Equals("H") ? PT.PA : PT.SP
```

Answer (score 9):

Historically, [`IIf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx) was commonly used for that - but that does not use short-circuiting so is not quite the same. However, [there is now a 3-part `If`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
hp.pt = If(iniFile.GetValue("System", "PT").ToUpper().Equals("H"), PT.PA, PT.SP)
```

that *does* use short-circuiting, and thus is identical to the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) in C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [If operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx)

```
hp.pt = If(iniFile.GetValue("System", "PT").ToUpper().Equals("H"), PT.PA, PT.SP)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `If` function like so:

```
x = If(condition, trueValue, falseValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is a duplicate of a question that has already been asked and answered:

[Is there a conditional ternary operator in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net)

here:

```
Dim foo as String = If(bar = buz, cat, dog)
```

Comment: You should flag the question as a duplicate then.

Comment: will do just that then