# SQL Data Reader - How to handle Null column values elegantly

Tags: vb.net, sqldatareader

I'm using an SQLDataReader to retrieve values from a database which may be null. I've worked out how to handle Null string values but can't get the same trick to work with integers or booleans:

```
Using cmd As DbCommand = store.GetStoredProcCommand("RetrievePOCO")
    store.AddInParameter(cmd, "ID", DbType.Int32, ID)
    Using reader As IDataReader = store.ExecuteReader(cmd)
        If reader.Read() = True Then
            Dim newPOCO As New POCO()
            With newPOCO
                'If the source column is null TryCast will return nothing without throwing an error
                .StatusXML = TryCast(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("StatusXML")), String)
                'How can a null integer or boolean be set elegantly?
                .AppType = TryCast(reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("AppType")), System.Nullable(Of Integer))
                .Archived = TryCast(reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Archived")), Boolean)
```

So how can a null integer or boolean be set elegantly? I've seen suggestions in C# but they don't translate correctly to VB giving a 'TryCast operand must be reference type, but integer? is a value type' compiler errors.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following function in this scenario:

```
Public Shared Function NoNull(ByVal checkValue As Object, ByVal returnIfNull As Object) As Object
    If checkValue Is DBNull.Value Then
        Return returnIfNull
    Else
        Return checkValue
    End If
End Function
```

Your code would look something like this:

```
With newPOCO
    .StatusXML = NoNull(reader("StatusXML"), "")
    .AppType = NoNull(reader("AppType"), -1)
    .Archived = NoNull(reader("Archived"), False)
End With
```

Note that this function requires you to pass the value which should be used if the value is DbNUll as the second Parameter.

Comment: I liked this idea, but in the function change "Return = checkValue" to "Return checkValue" (minor)

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of the [IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method of the SqlDataReader and use the [VB.NET ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net) to assign a default value to your poco object

```
.StatusXML = If(reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("StatusXML")), _
             "",reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("StatusXML")))
```

It is just one line, not very elegant because you need to call two times the GetOrdinal method.

Comment: Yeah it's not terribly elegant as you point out, I was hoping there would be something neater.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function NotNull(Of T)(ByVal Value As T, ByVal DefaultValue As T) As T
    If Value Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(Value) Then
        Return DefaultValue
    Else
        Return Value
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, you should also provide *how* the code answers the question, and in this case implementation steps for the OP's question.