# If statement inside data binding for repeater

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, repeater

I am trying to perform a ternary if statement inside my databinding for a repeater:

```
<%# If(Container.DataItem.rDate.isEmpty, String.Empty, Format(Container.DataItem.rDate.Date, "Short Date"))%>
```

This should be the equivalent to:

```
If rDate.isEmpty then
    String.Empty
Else
    String.Format(rDate, "Short Date")
End If
```

However, I get a compilation error at runtime: Expression expected @

```
<%# If(Container.DataItem.rDate.isEmpty, String.Empty, Format(Container.DataItem.rDate.Date, "Short Date"))%>
```

Any Ideas as to what is wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a conditional ternary operator in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net)

Comment: @IlyaBursov I know there is a ternary operator, my question has to do with why am I getting an error in my data binding.

Comment: Do you use VB.NET 2008? `maybe Container.DataItem.rDate.isEmpty = TRUE` will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that at runtime, IIS was using an older version of VB.Net so I had to use `IIF`, instead of `If`