# vb.NET If Then Replacement

Tags: vb.net

In a quick project, I have to use the If command to check if a radio button is checked or not, if it is checked I would make the Form's back color be replaced with the Radio button's forecolor. Example:

```
If rdoRed.Checked = True Then
Me.Backcolor = rdoRed.Forecolor
```

The teacher then challenged us to do this without the If/then commands, how would I come around this?

Comment: My suggestion is to not cheat on your homework.

Comment: Note the teacher challenged ***you***, not us...

Comment: Lol I already submitted my work, I was just looking for the answer

Comment: I just didn't take on the challenge of not using if/then since it was extra, but now that I'm done I want to find an answer

              Edit:              This is the code I submitted:                   

    If rdoRed.Checked = True Then
    Me.Backcolor = rdoRed.Forecolor Elseif
    If rdoGreen.Checked = True Then
    Me.Backcolor = rdoGreen.Forecolor Elseif etc.etc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try a ternary operator.

```
Me.Backcolor = If(rdoRed.Checked, rdoRed.Forecolor, [some other color])
```

Like this example:
[Is there a conditional ternary operator in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net)

Comment: OK... so this is a homework question.. but is it wrong?

Comment: Technically it is different and you could argue your case.

Comment: No, it would count as correct, but I was curious if I could carry out the same objective without using If/then

Comment: Well, thank you very much for your answer anyways, you did increase my knowledge on vb.NET and I'm sure to use this in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use `Select Case` here:

```
Select Case rdoRed.Checked
    Case True
       Me.Backcolor = rdoRed.Forecolor
    Case Else
       'Some other color 
End Select
```

And you can also use `IIF`

```
Me.Backcolor = IIf(rdoRed.Checked, rdoRed.Forecolor, Me.Backcolor)
```