# Using If Operator

Tags: vb.net

I have almost done the following using if else expression.But I want to code it using if operator.Consider the following data of several ages and I have to print the appropriate age using vb.net 2008.

if age between 0-12 then "child",
if age between 13-19 then "teen",
if age between 19-35 then "youth",
else adult.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between an [If Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx) used to control flow and the [If Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) which evaluates a condition to make an assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a `Select Case` statement might be more appropriate; especially so if changes to the age brackets may be coming in the future.

```
Dim age as long = 11
Select Case age
    Case 0 To 12
        Debug.WriteLine("0-12 - Child, inclusive")
    Case 13 To 19
        Debug.WriteLine("13-19 Teen, inclusive")
    Case 20 To 35
        Debug.WriteLine("20-35 - Youth, inclusive")
    Case Else
        Debug.WriteLine("Older than 35 - Adult")
End Select
```

You need to specify your age ranges more succinctly unless you are using a hierarchy of criteria. Is *19* a *Teen* or a *Youth*? By your narrative it is both unless the *Youth* criteria is not evaluated once *Teen* matches positive.

Comment: 19 is teen but I need this to be coded using if operator other than using select case statement.

Comment: @EKishni - If you want to code it in a less-than-best method then you must be within the strictures of a homework assignment. Edit your question to show what you have tried so far and more help may be forthcoming.

Comment: @Jeeped: You should get the teacher's salary if you're going to teach this joker better than the actual teacher.

Comment: In fact, how about we make a new tag, `homework`, and we can all get paid for doing other people's homework. :)

Comment: @TheBlueDog: I know it's difficult to see the sarcasm on my comments..  pretend its there.  (e.g. I agree with you).

Comment: @Dan-o: Yeah, I got the sarcasm, I was just using is as an excuse for a rant. :D

Answer (score -1):

For If operator go this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net)

```
Dim s() As String = {0, 1, 2 and so on }
If s.Contains(Age) Then
  'Go      
End If
```

i hope this help for your project ......:-)