# How to convert dbnull type to string

Tags: vb.net-2010

```
If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
    conn.Close()
End If
conn.Open()
sql = "SELECT *FROM tbL_books_transactions WHERE transactionID LIKE '%" & TextBox8.Text & "%'"
cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)

Dim dr As MySqlDataReader

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
If dr.Read = True Then
    TextBox4.Text = CType(dr("AccessionNo"), String)
    TextBox7.Text = CType(dr("BookTitle"), String)
    TextBox11.Text = CType(dr("DateBorrowed"), String).ToString()
    TextBox3.Text = CType(dr("userID"), String)
    TextBox10.Text = CType(dr("userName"), String)

Else
    MsgBox("No Student Record Exist")

End If
conn.Close()
```

Comment: Short answer: you can't. It's a null value. What value is coming up as DBNull? All you have here to go on is a code dump. I would just check each value returned in your datareader for null, and if equal to null, return an empty string, otherwise return the contents as a string.

Comment: what do you mean code dump sir sorry still a newbie in programming :(

Comment: you just dumped a bunch of code on the page.

Comment: i have another question how do you insert a date value from your database to crystal report viewer er cause ived tried to get my date value from database to crystal report but it does not show the date

Comment: Post your second question as a separate question on here and it might get answered. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to convert a column that contains a null value to something that you are able to work with your textboxes

```
Dim pos = dr.GetOrdinal("AccessioNo")
TextBox4.Text = if(dr.IsDbNull(pos), string.Empty, dr.GetString(pos))
```

In this example, first retrieve the ordinal position of the column that you are interested to read. Then use that value to call IsDbNull and put everything inside a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net) If the valus is null return an empty string otherwise the content of the field with GetString.