# Cannot insert null into database vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, null

I have been trying to insert null into database but every time I am getting failed. I tried several codes but nothing is working. When I tried this code:

```
   If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) Then
        TextBox2.Text = DBNull.Value
    Else
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text

    End If
```

It gives me an error :

```
Value of type 'System.DBNull' cannot be converted to 'String'.
```

And when I tried this:

```
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) = True Then
        TextBox2 = System.DBNull.Value
    Else
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text
    End If
```

It gives me an error:

```
  Value of type 'System.DBNull' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'.
```

Before these code I have added some validations in order to make the text box compulsory to filled by the user.

This is the place where I am getting this error:

```
    dsNewRow.Item("emp_name") = TextBox1.Text
    dsNewRow.Item("emp_age") = TextBox2.Text  'This is the place where I am getting this error'
    dsNewRow.Item("emp_gend") = ComboBox1.Text
    dsNewRow.Item("emp_dob") = DateTimePicker1.Text
    dsNewRow.Item("emp_mstatus") = TextBox4.Text
    dsNewRow.Item("emp_qual") = RichTextBox1.Text
    dsNewRow.Item("emp_exp") = RichTextBox2.Text
```

It also shows:

```
 Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <> in emp_age Column.  Expected type is Int32.
```

Comment: You are not inserting values to a database, you are assigning the `Text` property of a control. At which point the error you get is entirely reasonable.

Comment: Please show the code where you are attempting to write your values to the database. It is there that you should put the DbNull.Value.

Comment: A string is not convertible to `DbNull.Value`, you could use `String.Empty` instead. But what are you trying to achieve at all? Your code makes no sense at all.

Comment: Is the emp_age a column that allows NULL values?

Comment: @Steve I have edited my question again and inserted the error location

Comment: @TimSchmelter Actually I have created a form which includes several textboxes. When a user leaves a textbox empty and clicks save so at that point all I want is null should be inserted into DB. So to add null I wrote that piece of code.

Comment: @Steve Its a column in database having datatype number. I think it does accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DbNull.Value` could be assigned to a DataRow column using a syntax like this
(assuming, of course, that the `emp_age` column is nullable)

```
dsNewRow.Item("emp_age") = 
    If(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox2.Text), DbNull.Value, TextBox2.Text)
```

Here, you use the [If conditional operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net) to set the value of the column to DbNull.Value or to the TextBox2.Text

However, there is another problem not immediately visible. This `emp_age` column requires an integer value and you shouldn't write in it a string. It is better to check that input value to be sure that you have a valid integer value

```
Dim age As Integer
If Int32.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, age) Then
    dsNewRow.Item("emp_age") = age
Else
    dsNewRow.Item("emp_age") = DBNull.Value
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @steve for your help man. First code worked perfect. You are right if string is being inserted it will give an error but when I tried this code(2nd one) It give me an error:
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
on this line
`If Int32.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, age) Then`

Comment: Sorry It was my error, it worked now. Thanks @steve

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you try, `TextBox2.Text` will never be `DbNull.Value`. So you have to find a way to define the empty values. If you are allowed to treat empty strings as DbNulls, you could write:

```
dsNewRow.Item("emp_age") = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text), DbNull.Value, TextBox2.Text)
```

However this still requires the column `emp_age` to support DbNull values.