# Why IIF is evaluating the two sides ? .NET

Tags: .net, sequence, iif

I'm trying to use the IIF in a simple mode:

```
 Dim MyList As List(Of Double) = New List(Of Double)
 Dim ret As Double

 ret = IIf(MyList.Count > 0, MyList.Max(), 0)
```

There is no elements in MyList but a System.InvalidOperationException is thrown, "Sequence has no elements".
Why IIF is evaluating the two sides ?

Thanks!

Comment: [read this post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx) is the old VB6 function, use the [`If` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) which does short-circuit evaluation:

```
ret = If(MyList.Count > 0, MyList.Max(), 0)
```