# What is meaning of "?"

Tags: ternary

IF OFFSET >=0 THEN

TIME_LOCAL:= ((current_time + OFFSET)>24) **?** ((current_time + OFFSET) - 24) **:** (current_time + OFFSET);

else

TIME_LOCAL:= ((current_time + OFFSET) < 0) **?** ((current_time + OFFSET) + 24) **:** (current_time + OFFSET);

endif;

Comment: This isn't legal VBA... or VB.NET. What language is this?

Comment: In **VBA** the `?` token is a shortcut for the `Print` instruction (which is equivalent to `Debug.Print`), and the VBE (the editor) automatically changes `?` to `Print`; the `:` token is usually an *instructions separator* and is used to combine multiple statements on the same logical line of code, e.g. `For i = 0 To 100 : Debug.Print i : Next` - when used immediately after an identifier at the start of a line, it denotes a *line label*, e.g. `CleanFail:`, which can be used in `On Error` statements, e.g. `On Error GoTo CleanFail`, or simply with `GoTo` statements. Lines don't end w/ `;` in VB.

Answer (score 2):

The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression. Following is the syntax for the conditional operator.
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;

Comment: That's the *ternary* conditional operator, and it's not legal in VBA.

Comment: Yes, I agree. That code is not VBA. The tag needs to be changed. Which I cannot do.

Comment: I could, but apparently [there's no such ternary operator in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/q/576431/1188513), so I don't know what language this is.

Comment: I would guess C# that has been messed around with before posting. Maybe the OP could enlighten us

Comment: Whatever the language, it's a ternary operator. Have an upvote =)