# VBA assignment statement with an OR clause

Tags: vba

I've come across some code that looks something like this

```
If (condition) Then
    array(index) = array(index) Or variable
End If
```

Being unfamiliar with VB, it looks to me like some kind of horrid result of a love affair between an assignment statement and a condition clause.

Functionally, I thought it looked like some kind of ?: ternary operation. I now assume it is, though certainly not in a form I'm used to.

I'm aware that the first branch will assign array(index) to itself, that's essentially how the code I'm working on works. I don't THINK it's relevant to the question, but it kinda weirds me out, and there is often more going on than what I realize with VB.

Not a duplicate of [Is there a conditional ternary operator in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net) since that question is asking if there IS one, rather than "what the heck does this mean"

Comment: Is it VB.Net or VBA? Please correct tags accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What it's *not*.

There is no ternary operator in VBA. The closest you get is `IIf`, which evaluates both *true* and *false* expressions (so don't use it when either branch has side-effects!):

```
IIf({bool-expression}, {value-if-true}, {value-if-false})
```

So it's not anything like a ternary.

We don't know what's in `array(index)`, but let's assume it's some `Long`:

```
array(index) = SomeLongInteger Or variable
```

What you're looking at is a regular assignment:

```
foo = 42 Or variable
```

The runtime is going to assign `foo` with a value. So first it must compute the right-hand side of the assignment (`=`) operator:

```
42 Or Variable
```

The `Or` operator is often used as a *logical operator* in *Boolean expressions*.

However the above expression isn't a *Boolean expression*, and the `Or` operator isn't a *logical operator* here.

---

### What it *is*.

It's a **bitwise operator** (in VB the logical and bitwise operators are the same, which is indeed a bit (pun not intended) confusing). In the assignment `foo = 42 Or Variable`, `foo` will take the value of the *bitwise comparison* of `42 Or Variable`.

```
Debug.Print 42 Or 12 'prints 46
```

---

#### How?

Think in binary. This is 42:

```
00101010
```

This is 12:

```
00001100
```

Then you *bitwise-or* the two values (remember your *truth tables*? `True Or True = True`; `True Or False = True`; `False Or False = False`) and you get this:

```
00101110
```

..which is the binary representation for - that's right - 46.

---

So, `array(index) = array(index) Or variable` does the following:

- Read the value of `array(index)`
- Read the value of `variable`
- Bitwise-Or the two values
- Assign the result of that operation back to `array(index)`

Comment: What (in the OP's original code) makes the `Or` *not* a logical operator (though I can't tell if your answer really states that)?  Seems like logical vs. bitwise would depend on the types of variable involved ?

Comment: @TimWilliams AFAIK that's correct: these operators are *logical* operators when they're involved in a *Boolean expression*, and *bitwise* operators otherwise (with the operands possibly implicitly converted to long integers). Bitwise operations are commonly used to determine whether a flag is "on" when dealing with combined enum values, for example.

Comment: @TimWilliams actually the distinction between "logical" and "bitwise" operators seems pretty artificial when you consider that `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` (aka -1/`True`) `And 0` (aka `False`) gives you 0 either way, and `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 Or 0` gives you -1/`True` either way as well: in the end *everything* is bitwise ;-)

Comment: Yes I thought that would be the logical conclusion of following that path... ;-)

Comment: Your answer...makes sense in VB's occasional total-nonsense kind of way that I'm learning to hate O_o idk, hopefully it made sense at the time? Regardless, thank you for clearing it up.

Comment: @TimWilliams - It depends on the type of the variable it is being assigned to.  There's an implicit cast if a bitwise `Or` result is assigned to a `Boolean`.  It doesn't get cast if it's being assigned to a numeric type.