# ternary operator in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.net and want to use ternary operator.

```
 If prefixDt IsNot Nothing AndAlso prefixDt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
```

Myattempt:

**`Return (prefixDt IsNot Nothing AndAlso prefixDt.Rows.Count > 0) ? True: False`**

Error: `?` cannot be used here.

Comment: Return (prefixDt IsNot Nothing AndAlso prefixDt.Rows.Count > 0) ... return true or false. no need for ? :

Comment: impressive. I will do that. But just for learning purpose how to achieve what I asked for.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is one liner using the ternary (conditional) operator

```
return If (prefixDt IsNot Nothing AndAlso prefixDt.Rows.Count > 0, True, False)
```

But if you need to return immediately you can simply test if the boolean expression is true or false

```
return (prefixDt IsNot Nothing AndAlso prefixDt.Rows.Count > 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

VB.NET prior to 2008 did not have a ternary operator. It did have a ternary *function*, `IIf(cond, truePart, falsePart)`, but being a function, both `truePart` and `falsePart` would be evaluated before the function decided which to return.

In VB.NET 2008, a new *operator* was introduced that provides the same functionality as the `cond ? truePart : falsePart` ternary operator in C-like languages. This operator uses the `If` keyword and is expressed with function-like syntax:

```
safeQuotient = If(divisor <> 0, dividend / divisor, Double.PositiveInfinity)
```

In this example, `dividend / divisor` in the `truePart` is safe even if `divisor` is zero, because if `divisor` is zero, the `truePart` is completely ignored, and the division by zero will not occur.

For your example, as was pointed out by @nabuchodonossor, you would only be converting a Boolean value that is already `True` or `False` into the same `True` or `False` value, but for completeness, you can write it out exactly as @Steve showed:

```
Return If(prefixDt IsNot Nothing AndAlso prefixDt.Rows.Count > 0, True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note there is really no way to do this if you are not doing variable assignment.  But you can do something like this.

Label1.Visible = If(1=0,true, false)

C# does it better!