# Why is .NET Core 3.1 returning: Method not found: 'System.Object Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIf(Boolean, System.Object, System.Object)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-core

I am working with a .NET Core 3.1 project and it references legacy code written in VB.NET (there's no way around this).  When calling into the VB.NET library, I am hit with:

`Method not found: 'System.Object Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIf(Boolean, System.Object, System.Object)'.`

Everything was working fine, nothing has changed code wise that could be causing this. There was a point in time `IIf` hadn't been ported over by the .NET Core team, but it's been there a while now, certainly for the lifetime of this application.

Looking through the logs, it is clear the error has been coming and going. I suspect someone had a working build while others didn't. The error is therefore dependant on whoever builds and deploys. The developer with working application is now gone and no one noticed the issue because of reasons.

I've tried:

- Installing just about everything from the VS installer.
- Building from VS 2019 rather than 2022 as the application was originally built with
  2019.
- Clearing build folders (via clean and manually removing bin and
  obj folders)
- Ensured `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core` is on the system (it's in `C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\3.1.0\ref\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.dll`).
- Ensuring `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core` is referenced. (I can see it as
  part of `Microsoft.NETCore.App`)
- Ensuring the VB.NET library itself builds and operates as expected.
- Manually dumped `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.dll` in the bin directory hoping for a miracle.

Despite the reference to `Microsoft.NETCore.App` and the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core` assembly, it never actually gets output to the \bin folder.

Any ideas? Wasted a day head scratching.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method in dll throwing System.MissingMethodException: Method not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53816478/method-in-dll-throwing-system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found)

Comment: A Net library is missing on the server.  Older version of Net before 4.5 was cumulative that you needed all the older versions installed like Net 1.0,2.0, 3.0,3.5,4.0, 4.1,4.2, 4.3,4.4.  New versions of Net have older libraries in one Net version but eliminated obsolete methods.  You may also be using a library that is not Net was discontinued a long time ago and need to install the library by itself.  Usually these are ActiveX libraries before 2005.

Comment: I did search beforehand. It isn't the issue as the application will work and has worked. Also, as detailed in my post - .NET Core does support IIf. I'll have a go at installing older Frameworks.

Comment: You probably want to convert it to use the `If` operator instead of `Iif`: [Performance difference between IIf() and If](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/performance-difference-between-iif-and-if).

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Ideally I'd rewrite the library, but a for a wealth of reasons I am kind of stuck with what we have.

Comment: If you are not allowed to fix it, then perhaps moving to .NET Core is not viable, and whoever is in charge of the budget should be made aware of that. Having a fragile build is not a good business proposition, I suppose.

Comment: Does a small new project using `Iif` work? Just to test it in case that is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

Comment: @AndrewMorton - it did not work, however I have addressed the issue. I still have no idea how this ended up breaking. In the end as a last resort, I back tracked through all commits and found the first one where the issue appears. Starting afresh, I applied the changes manually to a new branch. File by file expecting to hit the problem (sure couldn't see it in the diffs). Annoyingly it worked without a hitch. JSON configuration files and new assets (pdfs) were pretty much the only changes. Very strange.